# Wordpress if(post_name === nameOfPost) not working

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, permalinks, staging

I am trying to display specific text at the bottom of a menu but I only want this text to show if I am looking at a certain menu. This is the code I have:

```
<?php get_post_type( $post ) ?>
<?php if ( $post->post_name === 'belden-village' ) : ?>
    <?php echo "<p>*For all groups of 8 or more, an 18% gratuity will be included on your guest check. Thank You</p>"; ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

This code works in staging but as soon as we moved the site live it no longer displays the text when it is supposed to. I am calling it by the "slug" and the slug is the same in both staging and live site. Any ideas why this has suddenly stopped working? This is my first experience taking a site live so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Computer never lie. It just mean that $post->post_name is different than 'belden-village'. Prod isnt the best place to debug, but you could try to put a hidden tag like that: `<!-- <?php echo $post->post-name; ?> -->`. Then you can look at the source to understand whats going on.

Comment: Could you give us the result of this? `var_dump($post->post_name);`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `is_single()` function?

```
<?php get_post_type( $post ) ?>
    <?php if ( is_single( 'belden-village') ) : ?>
        <?php echo "<p>*For all groups of 8 or more, an 18% gratuity will be included on your guest check. Thank
    You</p>"; ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

If you are looking for a page instead of a post you can use the `is_page()` function instead:

```
<?php get_post_type( $post ) ?>
    <?php if ( is_page( 'belden-village') ) : ?>
        <?php echo "<p>*For all groups of 8 or more, an 18% gratuity will be included on your guest check. Thank
    You</p>"; ?>
<?php endif ?>
```